# Listing non-blank cells in Excel based on adjacent column(s)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

Given columns A and B, I want to list the A-values that have a non-blank B-cell in their row, in column C:

```
A     B     C
One         Two
Two   x     Four
Three
Four  x
...
```

The best I came up with so far is

```
{=INDEX(A1:A4;MATCH(TRUE;B1:B4<>"";0))}
```

which gives me "Two" in C1, but how do I continue?

> ***Note:*** This a simplified version of my problem: in reality, there are multiple columns like B, so filtering is not an option. Moreover,
>   B and C are not in the same sheet, and I want the C-sheet to update
>   automatically whenever I edit the B-sheet, so copy&paste is not
>   practical either.

Comment: [This page at get-digital-help](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2012/11/29/lookup-and-return-multiple-values-from-a-range-excluding-blanks/) seems like it may help you when you begin to expand across sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

This will work for your example an can easily be adapted if you have headers, more columns, or more rows.

`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$4,SMALL(IF(ISBLANK($B$1:$B$4),"",ROW($B$1:$B$4)-ROW($C$1)+1),ROW(C1)-ROW($C$1)+1)),"")`

Enter the formula in C1 and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Expand the formula to C4 to get the full results for your example.

Headers or columns may now be inserted in the example and this will still work. To handle more rows, change the range `$A$1:$A$4` and `$B$1:$B$4` accordingly

See also Microsoft Support article [Finding the nth Value That Meets a Condition](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/101167).

Comment: I got this to work by changing `$A$4` and `$B$4` to `$6` or `$5` and **removing column headers**.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the formula to work with column headers.

Answer (score 2):

Why not filter the list in place? Filter the list based on column B for all rows where B is not *blank* e.g.

[image]

Then if you need it in column C, just copy and paste it. **Remember that once you filter some cells are hidden so copy/paste might not look correct until you clear the filter.**

Comment: Actually, I stated a simplified version of my problem: in reality, there are multiple columns like B, so filtering is not an option. Moreover, B and C are not in the same sheet, and I want the C-sheet to update automatically whenever I edit the B-sheet, so copy&paste is not practical either.

Comment: @warakawa then this suggestion is definitely not an option for you, but I'll leave it in case someone else happens upon it.

Answer (score 0):

All right, if you need a formula, this will work for the ***simple example***. I'm not entirely sure on how to expand it to include other columns (*yeah, I'll admit I cobbled this together it's been frustrating me*).

It's an array formula, so CSE (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shft</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>) and drag down.

`=INDEX($A$2:$A$6,SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$6<>"",MATCH(ROW($B$2:$B$6),ROW($B$2:$B$6)),""),ROW(A1)))`

I know this isn't the best way to do this, but until **[Barry](https://superuser.com/users/111645/barry-houdini)**, [Jerry](https://superuser.com/users/219090/jerry), [Excellll](https://superuser.com/users/76571/excellll) or **someone** comes along, it's the best **I** have.