# Count filled cells in row, given from adjacent column not being empty in Excel 2010,

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a two worksheets, one in which I have a list of tasks as well as several other columns listing the status of the task and one column listing if the task is imortant or not. In the other sheet, I want to display the name of the task, if the column for it being important has been filled in.

I have achieved this using the array formula displayed below, which I found "inspiration" for in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/748292/listing-non-blank-cells-in-excel-based-on-adjacent-columns) on this site. `=IFERROR(INDEX(PDCA!$B$10:$B$1048;SMALL(IF(PDCA!$L$10:$L$1048<>"";MATCH(ROW(PDCA!$L$10:$L$1048);ROW(PDCA!$L$10:$L$1048));"");ROW(PDCA!B1)));"")`

So far, so good. However, next to the name of the task, I also want to display how many of the status fields are filled in, but I am stumped as to how to do it. Have any of you people got any suggestions for how I should go about the task?

See [this Google drive document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RyNSKrqfyoIV5mV5kBmP__sV4RrEAM87-nH6RsOoYwI/edit?usp=sharing) for what the rough layout of my Excel-workbook is (I'm using Excel 2010).

I would much prefer if this could be done without using an UDF.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably an easier way with `sumproduct` but I can't figure it out right now.

So, say your table is `A9:L22` including headers. You use your array formula in `N9`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$10:$B$1047,SMALL(IF($L$10:$L$1047<>"",MATCH(ROW($L$10:$L$1047),ROW($L$10:$L$1047)),""),ROW(B1))),"")
```

In cell `O9` you can use this (volatile) function -

```
=COUNTA(OFFSET(INDIRECT("$D$"&MATCH(N9,$B$10:$B$22,0)&":$K$"&MATCH(N9,$B$10:$B$22,0)),9,))
```

Obviously change it to your regional settings and your ranges and adjust your offset.

[image]

Seriously though, I don't think this is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks so much for your suggestion, unfortunately I'm just on my way home from work now, so I can't test it out, but I'll give it a go tomorrow.  I've tried quite a few things myself too, without much progress so if you don't really recommend this solution, I may just give up and use and UDF instead, I think it would be fairly trivial to write. Again, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: VBA could do this a lot easier, yes. Someone else might come along with a more elegant solution, so you might not want to accept this answer yet

Comment: I'll withdraw the acceptance for now, then :-)